# Solder old Home-Cinema wire to Audio Jack Plug

Tags: audio, soldering

So I have this ancient Home-Cinema (Panasonic SA-HT540) and the main unit appears to be broken. The speakers should work just fine though.

I'm planning to solder the speaker-wire (which is a simple +/- cable) to an audio jack plug. I've tried positive -> audio and negative -> ground but it doesn't work. 
Is this impossible or am I overseeing something? I can provide pictures if needed.

Thanks in advance!
Aron

Comment: Do you think that the main unit does nothing at all? Why do you think connecting the speakers to the audio jack would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming those wires are actually connected directly to the speakers and not any other circuitry, then it should work like a normal speaker (pulses of power cause the speaker's electromagnet to turn on etc.) If the speakers are large you may need an amplifier to boost the input power.

You could try soldering the wires, and each speaker should have two wires. One connects to positive (or "signal", "audio", etc.), one to ground. On RCA jacks the ground is the outer shield and positive is the inner. It may not be working if the input current isn't high enough.

That said, I would buy a cheap speaker controller. 
[http://www.amazon.com/ELEGIANT-Amplifier-Booster-Stereo-Motorcycle/dp/B01AT6KKM2/ref=sr_1_6?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1461791619&sr=1-6&keywords=Amplifier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AT6KKM2)

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I actually got it to work yesterday, seems like I messed up my first attempt. The wires are indeed connected directly to the speakers. I'm planning to use it on my desktops Sound card so I hope no amplifier will be needed. Thanks for your answer!